# How to disable future month and year in monthpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using month picker, i want to restrict users from selecting future month and year. How can I achieve that ? 
I tried using

```
$("#month").monthpicker({ dateFormat: 'M-yy',
            autoSize: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,   
            maxDate: new Date().getMonth()

});
```

but with this i could only restrict future year, i can still select future month. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `maxDate: new Date()` will suffice. No need to put `.getMonth()`

Comment: This also just restricts the future year not the month. I tried it.

Comment: never heard of monthpicker try http://jsfiddle.net/Ls4bpcy4/

Answer (score 1):

By default, the year range starts 10 years ago and ends on 10 years from now, having the current year selected.

This and other settings can be overwritten on widget initialization:

```
options = {
    pattern: 'yyyy-mm', // Default is 'mm/yyyy' and separator char is not mandatory
    selectedYear: 2010,
    startYear: 2008,
    finalYear: 2012,
    monthNames: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']
};

$('#custom_widget').monthpicker(options);
```

> You can try this. This is working for me.

```
$('#my_widget').monthpicker('disableMonths', [1, 2, 11, 12]);
$('#my_widget').monthpicker('disableMonths', []); // re-enables all months
```

Reference From : [Month Picker Jquery](http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/)

Comment: You can try this above solution.